# Unmatching variable names and parameters inside a function but code is still working! Can someone please explain why?

Tags: python

This is a simple calculator application implemented in a very basic python program. Though the function have a and b as parameters, inside their definition they are able to do the calculation with different variable names (the variable names in which the arguments of the function were stored). The variables x and y are not defined inside the functions, then how can the function calculate the right answer?

```
def add(a,b):
    res=x+y
    print(res)

def sub(a,b):
    res=x-y
    print(res)

def mul(a,b):
    res=x*y
    print(res)

def div(a,b):
    res=x/y
    print(res)

ch='y'
while(ch=='y' or ch=='Y'):
    print("CALCULATOR MENU")
    print("Press 1 to add ")
    print("Press 2 to subtract ")
    print("Press 3 to multiply ")
    print("Press 4 to divide ")

    x=float(input("Enter the first number: "))
    y=float(input("Enter the second number: "))
    choice=int(input("Enter your choice: "))

    if(choice==1):
        add(x,y)
    elif(choice==2):
        sub(x,y)
    elif(choice==3):
        mul(x,y)
    elif(choice==4):
        div(x,y)
    else:
        print("wrong choice")

    ch=input("Do you want to continue?('y' or 'Y' for yes): ")
```

Comment: Possibly because the defined x and y are being used instead of parameters? It's running because x and y are declared before function calls

Answer (score 1):

Think about the stack as your program is executing. Because x and y are declared prior to the first call to add you are just adding 'global' variables. As its executing it goes through and does

```
x=float(input("Enter the first number: "))  # enters 5
y=float(input("Enter the second number: ")) # enters 10
choice=int(input("Enter your choice: "))    # enters 1

if(choice==1):                              # evaluates to true
    add(x,y)                                # calls add(x,y)

----------------------------------------------------------------

def add(a,b):                               # ignores a, b, they aren't used
    res=x+y                                 # looks for x and y, finds them declared above as global and sets res to 15
    print(res)                              # prints 15
```

Comment: But why are x and y being treated as global? Aren't they local to the while loop?

Comment: Yes, but when you call the functions they are in the while loop's scope and can therefore access the variables. Your scoping goes while->if->function. The function can access all the variables in the if statement and the while loop, the if statement can access variables in the while loop. The while loop cannot access variables declared in the if statement or the function. So when you declare x and y in the while loop, the function can access them.

Answer (score 0):

The x and y values are implicitly global. Your function is using the x and y defined in lines

```
x=float(input("Enter the first number: "))
y=float(input("Enter the second number: "))
```

This is considered a bad practice by most since your functions may have side effects and aren't explicitly stating its inputs in its definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "This is considered a bad practice by most since your functions may have side effects and aren't explicitly stating its inputs in its definition"?

Comment: Imagine you have a large program and access global variables like this in all the functions. Your source code would be difficult to read and becomes more likely to have unexpected behavior. When you look at a function, rather than seeing that the variables are arguments, you must go back and see how they were defined and modified. If you run your program and 5 * 5 + 3 = 32 you can't just call multiply(5, 5) to see if mul is working correctly, you only know that your final result is wrong and have to go through all the programs complexity to identify the problem.

Comment: @user120010 please update your answer with the extra details you have added in the comments. You'll increase the chances the answer will be found useful.